# Estimate covariance matrix from a sample of linear combinations

Tags: linear-model, covariance, latent-variable

Suppose you have a sample of $p$-dimensional weight vectors $\boldsymbol{w_i} = (w_{i, 1}, w_{i, 2}, ..., w_{i, p})$ and observations $y_i$ where $n \in \{1, ..., N\}$ and $j \in \{1, ..., p\}$.

Let $y_i = \boldsymbol{w}_i^TX_i = \sum_{j=1}^p w_{i, j} X_{i, j}$ where $X_{i} = (X_{i, 1}, X_{i, 2}, ..., X_{i, p})$ is a $p$-dimensional unobserved latent vector sampled independently for each $i$ from a multivariate normal distribution $N(\mu, \Sigma)$.

Is there a way to estimate the covariance matrix $\Sigma$?

Comment: I suspect you might not have phrased this question as intended.  You describe $np$ random variables and say they are "sampled from a multivariate normal distribution."  That *reads* like the covariance matrix will contain $(np)^2$ entries -- and evidently that cannot be estimated from just $n$ linear combinations.  Could you clarify the ambiguous meaning of "multivariate"? What are the dimensions of this distribution?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that there are $n$ independent draws from a $p$ dimensional multivariate distribution. So the covariance matrix should contain $p^2$ entries.

Comment: In this specific case, it is only possible if you postulate that the latent variables are orthogonal. Otherwise, you need the weights for the $X$ also.

Comment: @POC what do you mean by the weights for the $X$? I think I may still be unclear in my problem statement. Each observed $y_i$ is the outcome of the dot product $w_i^T X_i$ where $X_i$ drawn from $N(\mu, \Sigma)$. The weights are know, only the parameters of the $p$ dimensional distribution are not.

Comment: If there's no misunderstanding, could you please provide some insight into why this may only be possible with orthogonal latent variables?

Comment: I see no reason why the $X_i$ need to be orthogonal. Whether estimation is possible depends on how the $w_{i,j}$ are produced.  For instance, if they are all collinear, then for $p\gt 1$ you won't be able to identify most of the entries of $\Sigma.$  Could you therefore explain how these weight vectors arise?

Comment: It is possible for orthogonal or oblique latent variables. However, given the informations, I have to assume that variables in $X$ are independent. I might be confused as to what you are trying to accomplish. For instance, isn't there $(p+1)^2$ (accounting for $y$) entries in the covariance matrix? Are the $w_{i,j}$ specific to every subject? For me, this question is about trying to estimate the covariance matrix from $\beta$ (regression) coefficients.

Comment: Assume that the $\boldsymbol{w}_i$ span the full $p$-dimensional subspace. For example, assume they have been generated from a separate $p$-dimensional multivariate normal distribution. The $\boldsymbol{w}_i$ are specific and drawn independently for each subject. It is true that there are $(p+1)^2$ entries in the covariance matrix for each observation, but the observations are not iid r.v.s due to the weights.

Comment: Let $\mu$ be $\boldsymbol{0}$. Then if I were to fit a linear model, my $\beta$ would all be $0$. But I'm only interested in the variance of $Y = \boldsymbol{w}^T X$ given $\boldsymbol{w}$. For example, suppose that $X_i$ really follows the distribution $N\left(\boldsymbol{0}, \begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\right)$ for all $i$. Then the variance of each $Y_i$ depends only on $w_{i,1} - w_{i, 2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setting up the inference problem**

As described in the question, $\{X_1, \dots, X_n\}$ are i.i.d. Gaussian random vectors. Each observation $Y_i$ is generated by projecting the corresponding $X_i$ onto its own weight vector $w_i$ (which is assumed to be known):

$$X_1, \dots, X_n \underset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$$

$$Y_i = w_i^T X_i$$

Since we're linearly transforming Gaussian random vectors, each $Y_i$ is also Gaussian, with mean and variance given by [standard rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation):

$$Y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(w_i^T \mu, w_i^T \Sigma w_i)$$

Furthermore, the $Y_i$ are independent (but not identically distributed), so the joint distribution factorizes as:

$$p(y_1, \dots, y_n \mid \mu, \Sigma) =
\prod_{i=1}^n \mathcal{N}(y_i \mid w_i^T \mu, w_i^T \Sigma w_i)$$

The corresponding log likelihood function is:

$$\mathcal{L}(\mu, \Sigma) =
\sum_{i=1}^n \log \mathcal{N}(y_i \mid w_i^T \mu, w_i^T \Sigma w_i)$$

$$= -\frac{n}{2} \log (2 \pi)
- \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n \log (w_i^T \Sigma w_i)
- \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(y_i - w_i^T \mu)^2}{w_i^T \Sigma w_i}$$

The parameters can estimated by maximum likelihood:

$$\max_{\mu, \Sigma} \ \mathcal{L}(\mu, \Sigma)$$

Alternatively, if you can specify a prior distribution representing *a priori* knowledge/assumptions about the parameters, you could use MAP estimation or compute a full Bayesian posterior distribution.

**Maximum likelihood estimation**

I haven't checked whether a closed-form maximum likelihood solution exists, but encourage you to look into this yourself (based on the expression for the log likelihood above). As a quick test, I numerically optimized the log likelihood for some toy examples with properties similar to those described in the comments: known/fixed mean $\mu = \vec{0}$, full rank covariance matrix $\Sigma$, and weight vectors sampled i.i.d. from $\mathcal{N}(\vec{0}, I)$. This produced seemingly unique solutions (multiple random initial guesses converged to the same solution) that were close to the true covariance matrices (given sufficiently many observations).

**Existence of a unique solution**

The joint distribution above is an $n$-dimensional Gaussian distribution. Let $\vec{y} = [y_1, \dots, y_n]^T$ contain the observations and $W \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$ contain the weight vectors $\{w_1, \dots, w_n\}$ as its columns. Then the joint distribution can be written as:

$$p(\vec{y} \mid \mu, \Sigma) = \mathcal{N}(\vec{y} \mid W^T \mu, C)$$

where the covariance matrix $C$ is diagonal, with diagonal entries $C_{ii} = w_i^T \Sigma w_i$

Thus, the problem can be seen as finding a *constrained* $n$-dimensional covariance matrix $C$, which is parameterized by $\Sigma$. For a unique maximum likelihood solution to exist, every choice of $\Sigma$ must correspond to a unique $C$. This condition could be violated, for example, by linear dependence between the weight vectors, or by having too few observations.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: @TinaTurner glad to help

Comment: If $X_i$ are t-distributed rather than Gaussian, does the problem become much more difficult?

Comment: @TinaTurner Not sure offhand. You can follow the same logic I used when $\{X_i\}$ follow a different distribution. The first task would be to come up with an expression for the joint distribution of $\{Y_i\}$ (which of course would no longer be Gaussian). Searching for 'linear combination of student t' seems to return some papers that might be useful.

Comment: The log likelihood for a multivariate Cauchy distribution has a similar functional form (if I'm correct) to what you've provided in your answer: $-\mathcal{L}(\mu, \Sigma) \propto \sum_{i=1}^n |w_i^T \Sigma w_i|
+ \sum_{i=1}^n \log(1 + \frac{y_i^2}{w_i^T \Sigma w})$ Do you have any suggestions for how to approach this numerical optimization? I have decomposed the covariance matrix as a Cholesky product to reduce the number parameters, but still struggling. Would this be better as a seperate question?

Comment: @TinaTurner Yes, Cholesky decomposition can often be a good way to parameterize symmetric, PSD matrices for optimization (no longer a covariance matrix for multivariate T/Cauchy). Not sure what issues you're running into, but would be best to post this as new question